# reduce CPU usage in while loop

Tags: loops, while-loop, cpu-usage

How do you limit the CPU of a while loop? (cpu usage 100%)

In this case, the code which is inside the while loop:

```
 Sub start()

    listenerThread = New Thread(AddressOf Listen)
    listenerThread.IsBackground = True
    listenerThread.Start()
End Sub

enter code here

 Sub Listen()
    Try
        listener = New TcpListener(New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port))

        listener.Start()
     a:          While (True)
            Thread.Sleep(600)
            Dim c As New Connection(listener.AcceptTcpClient)
            AddHandler c.GotInfo, AddressOf GotInfo
            AddHandler c.Disconnected, AddressOf Disconnected
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        GoTo a
    End Try
  End Sub
```